# ios Autolayout in storyboard not showing controls in iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

I´m doing a simple tutorial of how to work in storyboards. I Created a project for iPhone, added a uibutton inside a view of a viewController in a storyboard. I made the correct constraints to center the button in portraint and landscape modes. If I run in any iPhone, the button the in simulator doesn´t show but if I run in ipad simulator it´s there, and the constraints working. Why?

Comment: Did you do your constraints settings with "Universal" selected (Boottom/Center in Interface Builder) ?

Comment: Ok i found it, I had to disable "Size Classes" in the file inspector.